# Macro variable increment previous month beginning month

Tags: sas

I have a macro variable in the below format. This variable is called mindt. I need to get the previous month and the beginning of that month. So, for example, the below is 2017-07-01. I need 2017-06-01 in a macro variable. How do I do this? I don't have the code to do this. Below is some code.

```
2017-07-01

%LET mindt=2017-07-01;
%PUT &mindt;
```

Comment: Please include anything you've tried, INTNX is where you can start for example. This may be helpful as well: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Macro-Variables-of-Date-and-Time/ta-p/475194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a one-liner

```
86   %LET MINDT = 2017-07-01;
87   %put NOTE: MINDT(&mindt) Minus 1 month %sysfunc(intnx(MONTH,%sysfunc(inputn(&mindt,YYMMDD,10)),-1),yymmdd10);
NOTE: MINDT(2017-07-01) Minus 1 month 2017-06-01
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Much shorter than my approach.

Comment: Basically the same but takes advantaged of the often overlooked second parameter FORMAT for the SYSFUNC function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, thanks for playing. Not going to take the credit though, a colleague helped me.

```
    %LET MINDT = 2017-07-01;

%MACRO TEST(INPUT_DATE);

%PUT DOING THIS FOR MINDT OF &INPUT_DATE.;

%LET MINDT_AS_DATE = %SYSFUNC(INPUTN(&INPUT_DATE., YYMMDD10.));
%LET MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE = %SYSFUNC(INTNX(MONTHS, &MINDT_AS_DATE., -1));
%LET MINDT_MINUS_ONE = %BQUOTE(')%SYSFUNC(PUTN(&MINDT_AS_DATE_MINUS_ONE., YYMMDD10.))%BQUOTE(');

%PUT MINUS ONE IS &MINDT_MINUS_ONE.;

%MEND;

%TEST(&MINDT.);
```